# Unexpected token name (PubNubAngular) UglifyJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack, babeljs

I got the below error while I build the Angular2-cli project using `ng build`. Project working fine when I ran `ng serve`.

`ERROR in main.33b89c04bc9dfd9d2b66.bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (PubNubAngular)`

I observed that error occur when I add the PubNub Angular2 in package.json.

```
"pubnub": "4.4.4",
"pubnub-angular2": "1.0.0"
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
}
}
```

Angular-cli version: `1.0.0-beta.20-4`
@angular/core version: `2.1.0`

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Note that you're running the _very_ old, deprecated "angular2", it's currently at version `2.4.9` and is called `@angular/core`. You should consider upgrading.

Comment: Just to second the previous comment, it will be almost impossible for you to find support for that version and the changes to the framework since then have been sweeping and massive.

Comment: Sorry, that one was angular-cli version. Updated the versions

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJs isn’t compatible with ES6 for therefore when the it is trying to create the minify version of all project it is not able; pubnub-angular2 v1.0.2 resolves this issue.